# i want to select by the Nearest Date

Tags: sql

using Oracle
I have this Statement to show `QtyAvailable` of stock in the a specific date

```
SELECT st.QTYAVAILABLE
FROM RV_STORAGE st
INNER JOIN m_product p
ON ( st.m_product_id =p.m_product_id)
INNER JOIN AD_Org org
ON ( org.ad_org_id          = p.ad_org_id )
WHERE st.DATELASTINVENTORY ?????? '1-AUG-2014'
AND st.M_PRODUCT_ID         = 1003965
```

but in the table `RV_Sorage` the `qtyAvailable` is calculate many time (inventory) so I want to Select the near `QtyAvailable` to my `DATELASTINVENTORY`

example

```
   id    qty    date
1003965   5   30-APR-10
1003965  168  18-DEC-13
1003965   0   31-DEC-08
1003965   0   31-DEC-08
1003965   5   24-JUL-12
1003965   5   30-SEP-13
1003965   0   30-SEP-13
1003965   2   21-MAY-14
```

result must be `2` from the line with the near date   `21-MAY-14`

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your example, your specified date is 31-OCT-12 and the result should be the Qty of 21-MAY-14 ?!?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: i correct my example sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understand well your problem. If you want the QTYAvailable for a defined date, here is the query you're looking for:

```
SELECT S.QTYAVAILABLE
FROM (SELECT S.QTYAVAILABLE
      FROM rv_storage ST
      WHERE ST.m_product_id = 1003965
          AND ST.datelastinventory < '1-AUG-2014'
      ORDER BY ST.datelastinventory DESC) S
WHERE ROWNUM = 1
```

Hope this will help you, i'm not familiar with Oracle.

Comment: Thank your for correcting your exemple. I updated my query, can you check if it works?

Comment: Thanks fro your time My friend your Querry work exactely like i want it