# show the latest date, not a random one, after group by in SELECT statement (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I could get the grouped results per the ticker into one row of results showing the total amount in this period. However, but the date display is not the latest. I want to have the date display the latest record.

```
SELECT Ticker, TimeStamp as 'Last Update', Sum(Amount)
WHERE Ticker = 'APPL'
GROUP BY Ticker
```

APPL, 20140827 11:05:03, 11016450

However, the last update date is 20140827 15:05:05, so the expected results is:

APPL, 20140827 15:05:05, 11016450

Comment: may be this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25544314/i-want-to-select-by-the-nearest-date

Answer (score 1):

Try this one.. May this help to you

```
SELECT Ticker, max(TimeStamp) as 'Last Update', Sum(Amount)
WHERE Ticker = 'APPL'
GROUP BY Ticker
```